# $\delta=0$ in Lyapunov's condition of CLT

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

In my textbook, Lyapunov's condition is shown to imply Lindeberg's condition by:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nE1_{(|X_{nk}|>c)}X_{nk}^2\le\sum_{k=1}^nE1_{(|X_{nk}|>c)}\tfrac{1}{c^\delta}|X_{nk}|^{2+\delta}\le\frac{1}{c^\delta}\sum_{k=1}^nE|X_{nk}|^{2+\delta}$$

Hence if $\sum_{k=1}^nE|X_{nk}|^{2+\delta}$ converges, so does $\sum_{k=1}^nE1_{(|X_{nk}|>c)}X_{nk}^2$.

What I don't get is why we need $\delta>0$. It seems like the above argument works just as well for $\delta=0$? Yet any source I can find requires $\delta>0$ which gives them a lot of problems with existence of moments.

Am I missing something totally obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lindeberg's condition is $1/s_n^2$ times your left side (with $c = \epsilon s_n$) $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  The $1/c^\delta$ (which becomes $1/(\epsilon s_n)^\delta$) with $\delta > 0$ is needed to make this go to $0$.

Let's look at the simple case where $X_{nk}$ are iid, and $s_n = \sqrt{n} \sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $X_{nk}$.  With $\delta = 0$, $\sum_{k=1}^n E[ X_{nk}^2] = n$, and after dividing by $s_n^2$ all you get is boundedness rather than convergence to $0$.

Comment: Ah right, it was actually also assumed that $\lim_ns_n=1$ (and $EX_{nk}=0$). I guess that's not standard. Perhaps the authors forgot that in their derivation of Lyapunov..

Comment: If you wish, you can rescale the random variables to make $s_n \to 1$.  It doesn't change the argument.  With $\delta = 0$ you'll have $\sum_{k=1}^n E[X_{nk}^2] = s_n^2 \to 1$, which still doesn't give you Lindeberg's condition.